# Is it possible to target just Simple Product from phtml template?

Tags: magento

I see something like:

```
     <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
```

and this

```
  <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
```

But couldn't find a way to target only the Simple Product type in similar manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative possibility you could assume a Simple product is on that is no other type.

```
<?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && !$_item->isSuper() && !$_item->isVirtual()): ?>
    <!-- Simple type only -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the rigtt direction. After my previous message, I'd realized "isComposite" is not Simple Product, so by targeting !$_item->isComposite() you can do something specific for Simple Products that exclude other product types.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ): ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a template file `catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml` that only displays for Simple type products.

If that doesn't show in the right place for you look in `layout/catalog.xml` for `<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>` to see how to make your own Simple-only template file.

Comment: Thanks! But that template works specifically for Product View page so it wouldn't work for thing that I want in other page such as Product listing, and catalog.xml isn't an option either.